# SOSQL Query for Contacts and Contact Roles

Tags: apex, contact

For a given account I need a list of all contacts and contact roles.
For example: if account a has three contacts and two of them have contact roles:

```
Contact.Name    AccountContactRole.Role
A               Purchaser
B               Influencer
C               null
```

Is this possible in one query or do I need to query all contacts and all contact roles separately?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[See the blog for SOQL subquery](http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-soql-subquery-and-custom-objects-with-apex.html)

You can use a inner query to achive this.

Try this code:

```
List<Account> accountList = [Select Id, Name,(Select id from AccountContactRoles), (Select Id from Contacts)   from Account where Id=: 'some id'];

System.debug('###'+accountList);

for(Account obj : accountList){
    System.debug(':::'+obj.Contacts);
    System.debug(':::'+obj.AccountContactRoles);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this will do what you need.

```
SELECT Contact.name, Role FROM AccountContactRole WHERE Account.id = XXXX
```